# How can I get the length of a string in TCPDF?

Tags: tcpdf

In TCPDF there is `GetCellHeight()` for measuring the height of a cell.

How do you measure the length or width of a string (or block of string) in TCPDF?

Answer (score 13):

The method to get the string length is [`GetStringWidth()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8075c1f04b6fbddc957cff786c4b16d9). Check also the [`getNumLines()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#af5cab8b0e1e29a3ee19a14007e37bd99) and [`getStringHeight()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ad68e86a862fe437a8ac1728cecaaa2e9) methods.